# How to grab the contacts from gmail using google API's in PHP?

Tags: php, contacts

In my project i want to grab the contacts from gmail using google API's. While executing code it does not showing contact list.  I provided userid and password in the code. Any help? Any working links or explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one will read this 1km long code. Just paste the crucial part and scope into smaller problems to get things solved.

Comment: You can refer this link. It has script in the php:-http://www.script-tutorials.com/google-api-get-contact-list/comment-page-2/